# eventResize is not working in fullCalendar2.6*

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I have recently upgraded fullCalendar 1.6 to 2.6, everything works fine other than `eventResize`.

I couldn't get resize arrow when I try to resize events , but `eventResize` was working perfectly in older version of fullCalendar .

Can anyone let me know how to achieve `eventResize` in fullCalendar 2.6.

Comment: Can you provide basic configuration of your calendar?

Comment: Thanks for your response . Couldn't get you , can you please explain what you are expecting ?

Comment: The function signature (parameters) changed from [1.xx](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_ui/eventResize/) to [2.xx](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventResize/) This may be the cause of your issues? Otherwise, eventResize appears to be working in 2.6 - what version of Moment.js, jQuery.js are being used?

Comment: Moment.js 2.11 and jQuery 2.1.4

Comment: It is good if you provide script of calendar. Like   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            eventResize: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { your code}
        });

Answer (score 0):

So 'eventResize' is a callback that is triggered when an event is resized. 'editable' is the option you set in the parameters that enables event resizing. (or 'eventDurationEditable' if you only want to allow resizing but not moving.)

Is it possible you no longer have editable or eventDurationEditable enabled? They did not change from 1.x -> 2.x

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    editable: true,
    ...
});
```